# Seeing the output of an already running program?

Tags: command-line, output

When I start the program in the terminal I see the output. I can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> my way out of it to use the terminal again, but is there a way to get the output of it into the terminal again?

I am aware that I can direct the output into a file and read that but it would be nice to have it back on the screen again for testing.

Comment: i am not clear..you want the output after you close the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sends a SIGINT signal to the process running in the terminal's foreground, terminating it unless the process is deliberately ignoring SIGINT signals;

So by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> you're telling the process running in the terminal's foreground to terminate.

To run a process preventing it to occupy the terminal you can start it into the background by appending `&` at the end of the command:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bash script.sh &
[1] 24961
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$
```

If you started a process in the foreground already, you can still stop it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bash script.sh
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 bash script.sh
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$
```

And send it into the background and resume its execution by using the `bg` built-in:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bg
[1]+ bash script.sh &
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$
```

You can send multiple processes into the background:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bash script.sh &
[1] 24961
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bash script.sh &
[2] 24984
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ bash script.sh &
[3] 24989
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$
```

You can list all the processes into the background by using the `jobs` built-in:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ jobs
[1]   Running                 bash script.sh &
[2]-  Running                 bash script.sh &
[3]+  Running                 bash script.sh &
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$
```

To move one process from the background to the foreground, you can use the `fg` built-in passing the job number as an argument:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ fg %1
bash script.sh
```

Running `fg` without specifying a job number as an argument will have the effect of moving to the foreground the last backgrounded process:

```
user@user-X550CL:~/tmp$ fg
bash script.sh
```

Comment: thank you, i was unawear that ctrl-c actually killed the process (this explains a lot!) the only time i used ctrl-c was to get back to the terminal and `pkill` that process! What you say makes sense, and to confirm, when i `fg` a particular process it will return to the foreground an i will be able to see its output again?

Comment: @ThriceGood Yes, check the last example. `^C` means that I hit Ctrl+C, but the process was actually running in the foreground. Try running e.g. `watch -n 1 echo foo &` and then running `fg`, you'll see that the process, brought to the foreground, will start outputting to the terminal again. You can then hit Ctrl+Z / run `fg` to toggle it from running in the background to running in the foregroung

Comment: excellent so far so good, when i `ctrl-z` a foreground process i get back to the terminal. when i run `jobs` it tells me that the process is `stopped`, what does this mean? that the process itself is stopped or its just stopped being in the foreground? because the process listens on a port, even when its saying stopped `netstat` tells me that the process is still listening, it could be just saying that the port is bound but the process itself is stopped. can you clarify this for me?

Comment: @ThriceGood Sorry, I mistakenly removed the relevant part while editing; the process is stopped and sent to the background; to resume its execution *without* bringing it to the foreground use the `bg` built-in; without an argument it will resume the execution of the last backgrounded process

Comment: @kos Just out of curiosity, what do the `+` and `-` symbols after the job number in square brackets mean in e.g. the `jobs` output?

Comment: @ByteCommander They just indicate the last and the second-to-last backgrounded process, I think it's done to give an idea of which processes would pop out of the stack first when issuing `fg` / which processes would resume the execution first when issuing `bg`

Answer (score 2):

Start your application or command via

```
command &
```

and don't use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. You will see the output until you close the terminal.

Bring the command back into foreground with

```
fg
```

---

*Example*

Create a simple script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    echo foo
    sleep 5
done
```

Start the script, the program will output the word `foo`. After some time I entered **`echo bar`**, followed by `fg` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> to terminate the script.

```
$ ./foo &
[1] 29544
$ foo
foo
foo
echo bar
bar
$ foo
foo
fg
[1]  + 29544 running    ./foo
foo
^C
```